# My MVC project is for .NET Core 7.0 does not boot due to an error "rtc rewrites exited with code -2147450750."

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have created a new MVC project on ASP.NET Core. When trying to launch a newly created project, the following error is displayed "rtc rewrites exited with code -2147450750." . All the solutions I found relate to Core 3.1, but I use 7.0.

I tried changing the json file "%LocalAPPDATA%\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\2.2.2\manifest.json", as indicated in the answers for Core 3.1, but it was serviceable from the very beginning. Attempt to delete folders .vs, bin, obj didn't give anything either. As well as an attempt to clean the NuGet package cache.

Comment: Where do you get your error? Local or Azure? Besides, you can check you SDK and runtime use CLI: [How to check that .NET is already installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/how-to-detect-installed-versions?pivots=os-windows#check-sdk-versions). You can create a new project to see whether it wok.

Comment: The error occurs locally. When trying to check the SDK returns the error "Failed to load the dll from [C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\7.0.9\hostfxr.dll], HRESULT: 0x800700C1
The library hostfxr.dll was found, but loading it from C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\7.0.9\hostfxr.dll failed
  - Installing .NET prerequisites might help resolve this problem.".

Comment: When running cmd from C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet outputs the following information:
Host:
  Version:      7.0.9
  Architecture: x86
  Commit:       8e9a17b221

.NET SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

Comment: .NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.20 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.9 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.20 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.9 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.20 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Comment: Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.9 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Other architectures found:
  x64   [C:\Program Files\dotnet]
    registered at [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\InstallLocation]

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found

Comment: I solved this problem by removing a non-working link to x64 from the environment variables. Yes, I would like it to work in the 64-bit version, but the main thing is that it works.

Comment: Qing Guo, thank you so much for the right questions, you helped a lot to get on the right path of solution.